Why is the weight monodromy hard in mixed characteristics?
I know very little about the conjecture, beyond Grothendieck's monodromy theorem perhaps (a dense open subgroup of inertia acting unipotently on pure motives). But I heard that it was completely solved in characteristic $p$, and using Scholze's perfectoid spaces, also for hypersurfaces of toric varieties.
What is it about pure $\mathbb{Q}_p$-motives that makes the conjecture that much harder?

The problem is with motives over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and not over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Could you elaborate? Isn't it a conjecture that for $X$ a smooth proper over $\mathbb{Q}p$, (so that its neron model is not necessarily proper over $\mathbb{Z}p$), and $l\neq p$ a prime of bad reduction, $H^i{et}(\overline{X},\mathbb{Q}l)$ becomes unipotent upon restriction to a dense open subgroup of $I_p$, and that there is a certain monodromy operator, and a certain filtration $M{\bullet}$ associated to it, such that $Gr_jH^i{et}(\overline{X},\mathbb{Q}_l)$ w.r.t. the monodromy filtration is pure of weight $j+i$? Are you saying this is a theorem? Do you have a reference?

I am not saying anything like this. Yet $I_p$ doesn't make any "motivic sense" if you consider $\mathbb{Q}_p$ "just as a field" that has no relation to $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

As about motives: any Chow motif over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a retract of a motif of a regular scheme that is proper over $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Hence it suffices to prove the conjecture assuming that a lift of this sort exists.

Weight-monodromy allows any prime $\ell \neq p$, and you cannot say the words "Neron model" unless $X$ is an abelian variety. If you don't understand the formulation of the conjecture, how could you expect this question to help you?

Fair point, indeed I am caught again for not reading the book on neron models, knowing how they are constructed, or that their construction is limited to abelian varieties. I do feel however that I have the ability to understand an experts answer to a level which might quench some of my curiosity, or perhaps help me frame this space of knowledge in terms of related problems/key references on the subject. I do not aim to represent knowledge I don't have, but am very eager to learn nonetheless. And interactions such as these are helpful, albeit your skepticism.
